# Spring property injection with interface default method

Tags: java, spring, interface, properties, inject

Is there a way to return an injected property in an interface default method? I want any class that implements `MyInterface` to get a method `getBar()` that returns a property value, without having to reimplement it in every class.
I'm essentially trying to do something like

```
public interface MyInterface {
  String getFoo();

  default String getBar() {
    return @Value("${my.prop.bar}"); //if only
  }
}
```

Normally I'd just do a private field and put @Value on it, but interfaces can't have non-constant fields. I think I could change from interface to an abstract class and make it work, but I'd rather leave as interface and give implementors the opportunity to extend whatever they want.

Comment: This is a case for composition over inheritance. You're basically doing the same thing as the (discouraged) pattern of implementing interfaces solely for constants.

Comment: @chrylis well, the interface does mostly act as a contract and has many other methods. But all classes implementing the contract need to return one property constant.